# 'IncompatibleClassChangeError' while returning SseEmitter as response in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, server-sent-events

I am trying to implement Server Sent Event in java spring MVC with xml based configuration.But I am getting the following error message while hitting the following URL: /subscribe-sse

Java Version:

```
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'

Servelet API: 4.0.1
spring-webmvc:5.2.0
spring-web:5.3.8
```

Controller:

```
    @GetMapping(path = "/subscribe-sse", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public SseEmitter subscribe() {
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        return emitter;
    }
```

Error I am getting:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expected non-static field org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.logger
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:502)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:596)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

I was trying to implement Server Sent Event with spring boot but getting IncompatibleClassChangeError

Comment: This generally means that you have incompatible versions of dependencies on your classpath. For example, spring-web-mvc and spring-web **must have the same version**, while you have version 5.2.0 for one and 5.3.8 for another.

Comment: Thank you @MarkRotteveel 

After changing both version to 5.3.29 and adding <async-supported>true</async-supported> on web.xml the problem resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem by following @Mark Rotteveel's comment.

The problem was with incompatible spring version. After using 5.3.29 for both spring web and web-mvc the problem has resolved. I additionally added `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` on web.xml for async to enable async request.